# Java - Client/Server Game Server Protocol. How to transmit commands?

Tags: java, client-server

I wrote a client-server pair for a 2D top down RPG game using sockets.  However, I'm not clear on how exactly to transmit what the user wants to do.

Would I simply transmit a string like "Move north" and then use switch statements to decide what action to take or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I would do this with compressed commands to get more command frequency. "mn" for move north or maybe "3" for move north

Answer (score 2):

If both client and server are java programs, then I would go with [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern where each command class does a specific job (like "Move north" in your case) and the command objects are exchanged between the client and the server.

We used to use this approach in our enterprise application (though not a game), while implementing multi-master replication and it was quite extendible without any if/else chains or switch statements anywhere, just receive command and call command.execute() without worrying about what the command is.

Comment: So i would create a new class for each command, and then send the entire object through the socket?

Comment: Right, you would define a command interface and then implement this interface for each distinct command you need in your app. The command will contain the data that is needed for execution and is built based on a user action. Such a command is sent through the socket using a serialization/deserialization library (or java's ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream), typecast the Object to your Command interface and just call execute on it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, since you "used to use" the Command pattern, what was it replaced with?

Comment: We moved to a single DB mode later on (during organizational changes) :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, basically. You can transmit strings, integers, whatever you want. You basically write the commands to the OutputStream you can get from the network socket on the client side, and read them in on the InputStream on the server side.

You can wrap the Input/OutputStream objects that come from a [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) with other stream types, such as [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) / [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), which allow you to read/write full objects and primitive types directly to the stream, the same way you would read/write data to a file on your file system using these same stream types.

Reading/writing to the network is really no different than read/writing from/to any other place, except that in networking you have to first establish a connection via a socket. Once you've got that socket and a proper stream type setup you just read/write data the same way you would anywhere else in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raw parsing from stream, I think you should choose a Serialize library to do this.

I suggest Protocol Buffers or FlatBuffers.

Just transmit bytes array and they will parse to Object for you.